# Дождаться окончания загрузки всех изображений, после чего пускать пользователя

Tags: android, img, imageview, picasso, glide

Всем привет! Мне необходимо реализовать следующее:
При запуске экрана загружаются данные с сервера. Всё это время пользователь видит прогресс бар. После того, как данные загружены, необходимо загрузить изображения по ссылкам из этих данных. Но необходимо дождаться, пока все изображения будут загружены, и только потом прятать прогресс бар и отображать информацию. Вопрос: как можно реализовать ожидание завершения загрузки изображений? Каждое изображение находится в ViewHolder списка, ума не приложу, как можно к этому подступиться.

Comment: покажите код загрузки картинок, чтобы можно более предметно говорить. Без кода сложно помочь

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать ForegroundService который будет по очереди подгружать файлы во временное хранилище при помощи DownloadManager